# Pause and resume of Enterprise application download on iOS

Tags: ios, http, http-headers, partial, resume

when downloading an application from AppStore, it's possible to pause the download by tapping the icon, or to continue the download after a network failure

We are trying to achieve the same for Enterprise applications through our private store.
We got it working for Android using Http Partial content (status 206) and we are unable to do the same for iOS.

Once an app download is in progress, tapping the icon has no effect and if network connexion is lost, download failed.
We got an eye on http requests made by AppStore application, set same http headers on our private app store but it doesn't help.

So is it possible to implement this behaviour ?

Comment: what do you need this functionality for? are your apps too large to download in one sitting?

Comment: large apps is a reason, but currently the pb is more related to bad network connections particularly when you are on the Edge network or when moving in a building for example. And download failures irritate our clients.

Comment: I use the enterprise distribution method (but not for a business), and my downloads don't pause either.

Comment: tested with ios 6 and 7

Comment: Yeah I don't know of a solution. Maybe file a bug report with apple for it.

Comment: this question needs an answer !

Comment: finally it was related to a bad header in http request:/